# I want to open a third activity when I reopens the app

Tags: android, android-studio, android-layout

I have used Share preferences for going from splash screen activity to login and after login there is another activity where other details have to be entered. And based on the checkboxes other activities will load (if 1st checkbox is checked then Home activity will load, if 2nd checkbox is checked then Home2 activity is loaded and if 3rd checkbox is checked then Home3 activity is loaded). Now I have managed to go from splash screen activity to third activity when I reopens the apps skipping the login activity. But Now I am confused about how can I skip the third activity. I have added the codes Please anyone help.

The Splash screen :

```
 public class MainPage extends AppCompatActivity {

ProgressBar pb;
Handler h = new Handler();
int count = 0;
Timer timer;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


    pb = (ProgressBar) findViewById(R.id.progressBar);

    timer = new Timer();
    TimerTask timerTask = new TimerTask() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            count++;
            pb.setProgress(count);
            if(count == 99){
                h.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {

                        SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = getSharedPreferences(Login.PREFS,0);
                        Boolean hasLoggedIn = sharedPreferences.getBoolean("hasLoggedIn",false);

                        if(hasLoggedIn){
                            Intent intent = new Intent(MainPage.this,BabyDetails.class);
                            startActivity(intent);
                            finish();
                        }
                        else {
                            Intent i = new Intent(MainPage.this, Login.class);
                            startActivity(i);
                            finish();
                        }


                    }
                },10);


            }
        }
    };
    timer.schedule(timerTask,0,100);


}
}
```

Login activity:

```
public class Login extends AppCompatActivity {

private ConstraintLayout layout;
private TextInputLayout lay_login_mobile, lay_login_password;
private TextInputEditText mobileedittext,passwordedittext;
private DBase dBase;
private User user;



public static String PREFS = "prefsFile";
Button b1;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_login);

    initview();
    initListener();
    initObject();



}

private void initview(){
    layout = findViewById(R.id.login_layout);

    lay_login_mobile = findViewById(R.id.lay_login_mobile);
    lay_login_password = findViewById(R.id.lay_login_password);

    mobileedittext = findViewById(R.id.loginmobile_edit);
    passwordedittext = findViewById(R.id.loginpassword_edit);

    b1 = findViewById(R.id.Loginbtn);

}

private void initListener(){
    b1.setOnClickListener(v -> {


        String mob = mobileedittext.getText().toString();
        String pass = passwordedittext.getText().toString();
        if(mob.equals("") || pass.equals("")){
            Toast.makeText(Login.this, "Enter all the fields", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        } else {
            if(!dBase.checkUser(mobileedittext.getText().toString(),passwordedittext.getText().toString())) {
                Toast.makeText(Login.this, "Invalid Credentials. Check Mobile number or Password", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
            else {
                Toast.makeText(Login.this, "Login Successful", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                Intent intent = new Intent(Login.this, BabyDetails.class);
                startActivity(intent);
            }
        }
        SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = getSharedPreferences(Login.PREFS,0);
        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPreferences.edit();
        editor.putBoolean("hasLoggedIn",true);
        editor.commit();
    });

}

private void initObject(){
    dBase = new DBase(Login.this);
    user = new User();
}
```

Third Activity :

```
public class BabyDetails extends AppCompatActivity {
DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener setListener;
TextInputLayout lay_baby, lay_date;
TextInputEditText et_date, et_baby;
RadioGroup radioGroup;
RadioButton radioButton;
TextView tv, tv2;
CheckBox cb1, cb2, cb3;
Button gotohome;
private DbaseBaby dbaseBaby;
private Baby baby;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_baby_details);

    initview();
    initObject();
    cb1 = findViewById(R.id.years03);
    cb2 = findViewById(R.id.years36);
    cb3 = findViewById(R.id.years69);
    gotohome = findViewById(R.id.next03);
    calender_func();


    gotohome.setOnClickListener(v -> {
        try {

            if (cb1.isChecked()) {
                baby.setBaby_name(et_baby.getText().toString());
                baby.setBirthdate(et_date.getText().toString());
                baby.setGender(radioButton.getText().toString());
                baby.setAge("0-3 years");
                Long id = dbaseBaby.addBaby(baby);
                dbaseBaby.addBaby(baby);

                Intent intent = new Intent(BabyDetails.this, Home.class);
                intent.putExtra("added_id", id);
                startActivity(intent);
                finish();
            } else if (cb2.isChecked()) {
                baby.setBaby_name(et_baby.getText().toString());
                baby.setBirthdate(et_date.getText().toString());
                baby.setGender(radioButton.getText().toString());
                baby.setAge("3-6 years");
                Long id = dbaseBaby.addBaby(baby);
                dbaseBaby.addBaby(baby);

                Intent intent = new Intent(BabyDetails.this, Home2.class);
                intent.putExtra("added_id", id);
                startActivity(intent);
                finish();
            } else if (cb3.isChecked()) {
                baby.setBaby_name(et_baby.getText().toString());
                baby.setBirthdate(et_date.getText().toString());
                baby.setGender(radioButton.getText().toString());
                baby.setAge("6-9 years");
                Long id = dbaseBaby.addBaby(baby);
                dbaseBaby.addBaby(baby);

                Intent intent = new Intent(BabyDetails.this, Home3.class);
                intent.putExtra("added_id", id);
                startActivity(intent);
                finish();
            }
            Toast.makeText(BabyDetails.this, "Login Successful", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    });
    trying();


}

private void initview() {
    lay_baby = findViewById(R.id.lay_babyname);
    lay_date = findViewById(R.id.lay_babydob);
    et_baby = findViewById(R.id.et_babyname);
    et_date = findViewById(R.id.et_babydob);
    radioGroup = findViewById(R.id.radiogroup);
    tv = findViewById(R.id.age_group);
    tv2 = findViewById(R.id.gender);

}
private void calender_func() {
    Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
    final int year = calendar.get(Calendar.YEAR);
    final int month = calendar.get(Calendar.MONTH);
    final int day = calendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);

    et_date.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            DatePickerDialog datePickerDialog = new DatePickerDialog(
                    BabyDetails.this, new DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener() {
                @Override
                public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int year, int month, int day) {
                    month = month + 1;
                    String date = day + "/" + month + "/" + year;
                    et_date.setText(date);
                }
            }, year, month, day);
            datePickerDialog.show();

        }
    });
}

private void initObject() {
    dbaseBaby = new DbaseBaby(BabyDetails.this);
    baby = new Baby();

}

public void checkRadioButton(View v) {
    int radioID = radioGroup.getCheckedRadioButtonId();
    radioButton = findViewById(radioID);
    Toast.makeText(BabyDetails.this, "Selected: " + radioButton.getText(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}

public void trying() {
    try {


        cb1.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
                if (cb1.isChecked()) {
                    cb2.setEnabled(false);
                    cb3.setEnabled(false);
                } else {
                    cb2.setEnabled(true);
                    cb3.setEnabled(true);
                }
            }
        });

        cb2.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
                if (cb2.isChecked()) {
                    cb1.setEnabled(false);
                    cb3.setEnabled(false);
                } else {
                    cb1.setEnabled(true);
                    cb3.setEnabled(true);
                }
            }
        });

        cb3.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
                if (cb3.isChecked()) {
                    cb2.setEnabled(false);
                    cb1.setEnabled(false);
                } else {
                    cb2.setEnabled(true);
                    cb1.setEnabled(true);
                }
            }
        });
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
     }
  }
```

Comment: what about another condition inside has loggedin ```if(hasLoggedIn){ if(doyouwantskipflag){}else{   Intent intent = new Intent(MainPage.this,BabyDetails.class);
                            startActivity(intent);
                            finish();}} ```   .in mainpage.java

Comment: Do I have to create another boolean method `doyouwantskipflag` or what please explain

Comment: store a doyouwantskipflag in your sharedpreference after opening third activity.and check that value in mainpage.java.if doyouwantskipflag is true then go to homeactivity else (false) thirdactivity.

Comment: Tried that giving me error of null pointer exception invoking virtual object on a null object refernce

Comment: you must check not null .Because we are adding that value in babydetails or home activity.so first login get null exception  .so you check .sharepre.getboolean("doyouwantskipflag")!=null.

Answer (score 0):

Probably The issue is because you are using Boolean value for redirecting the user simply try this code:

```
    SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = getSharedPreferences("studentData", MODE_PRIVATE);
    String name1 =sharedPreferences.getString("sName","noData");
```

// here "noData" is default value you can compare it if there is no existing value

```
    if (!name1.equals("noData"))
    {
        Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this,ThirdActivity.class);
        startActivity(intent);
    }
    else
    {
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Register a Student", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
```